# MySQL: would it be better to create more databases, or use an ID?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a web based RPG game, and I want the ability to run different "servers" but I'm not sure what the best way to go about it would be.

**First idea:** Create a table which would be named, "world" when a character is created, they get to choose a world to join, there by getting a world_id which would be used to tell what world they are in.

**Second idea:** Create a whole new database from a template and then using a session with an ID, and a switch table to connect to the right database.

Keep in mind I want people to be able to make new quests, items, mobs, and more on their own server, with out effecting the others. I know it could be done with the first idea, but I'm not sure if that would be the best way, since i would always need to check world_id for any change. I'm also a bit worried about using a session to change the database, but since it would be in a switch case, I don't think anyone could use that to do a MySQL inject.

**P.S:** I want the users account to be for all databases, so they don't have to create a new account to play on another database, or posts in the forum.

**EDIT:** I don't mean running several MySQL server, what I mean is to use something like this

```
function openConnection($db = 0){
    switch($db){
        case 1: $db_name = "database_two"; break;
        case 2: $db_name = "database_three"; break;
        case 3: $db_name = "database_four"; break;
        case 4: $db_name = "database_five"; break;
        default: $db_name = "database_one";
    }

    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname={$db_name};","<user>","<password>");
        $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn -> exec("SET NAMES utf8");
        $conn -> exec("USE {$db_name};");
        return $conn;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "<b>ERROR:</b> ".$e->getMessage(); exit;
    }
}
```

To keep all gaming data in separate databases.

Comment: in my option the first way would be more simple than creating a whole new db from scratch

Comment: You haven't really given enough context on overall system architecture. Why the need for multiple servers as opposed to multiple environments within the same server or cluster of servers?  If individual servers, do your MySQL databases run on the same servers as the application or are they abstracted out into their own DB server(s)?  Are the servers being set up for geographic reasons (i.e. servers a multiple location around the globe to improve latency? Are user accounts handled with application directly calling database or is there a separate user account service?

Comment: @MikeBrat I think you are stuck with the word "server", which was only mentioned once in my post. They would all run in the same MySQL server and user. But in different databases to keep the primary key low, and make sure that if a admin want to change something about the game, it have no possibility to change for the other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Yemto, I'm also working on a web-based RPG.

Try to change the way you view the database. The database is a way to store and organize data points which you can make accessible to the user if they request it...

So I don't really see the need for all the complications of "switch" tables and such, when you can just store all the world data you need in one database, and pass it to the user.

You can work on joining tables within the same DB if you need to gather multiple table data matching specific criteria, matching the passed in user_id SESSION, for example:

```
$qry = 
    'SELECT us.*, w.*, q.* 
    FROM user_stats us
    INNER JOIN worlds w ON (w.world_id = us.world_id)
    INNER JOIN quests q ON (q.quest_id = us.current_questnum)
    WHERE us.user_id_fk = "' . $_SESSION['userid'] . '"';
```

Then, using those matches and returned data (like, for that $_SESSION user id, return world 2), you can generate the new "world" entity/environment on the front end (using your engine... maybe instantiate a new class, which initializes a tilemap and other objects within it) and deliver it to the user.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, that's why I suggested the first idea, where another "server" will just give the character an world_id to get all the settings, quests, and other things that would be specific for that world. But I was wondering if it would be better to use different databases to keep the primary key low, and all the data separate for security reasons.

Comment: @Yemto Well it depends what your goals are... what your needs are for architecture (as Mike stated above). What data are you trying to secure? Why would keeping your `world id` in a separate server be helpful and make your application more secure? I would say maybe personal info collection or payment info might be separated into a separate server from gaming data... that may make sense.

Comment: oh I don't plan on just keeping the `world id` in a separate server. I was thinking of storing all gaming data into different databases, but on the same MySQL server, that way it would be easier for the person that runs a different database, to make changes. Otherwise I would need a tables to make sure no mobs, quests, items, and more, isn't in the wrong world.